# Unable to parse date and time separately

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have a following code that read data from a SQL Data reader and put it into a collection.

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    itemFeed.Add(new Item
    {
        itemTypeId = (int)sdr.GetValue(0),
        itemDate = (DateTime)sdr.GetValue(5), //Incoming: 2014-09-07
        itemTime = (DateTime)sdr.GetValue(6), //Incoming: 21:29:18.1030000
    });
    i++;
}
```

The issue is when the incoming value of `2014-09-07` is converted into date time it automatically adds time to it and it becomes `2014-09-07T00:00:00`, and for casting the time it fails because of invalid format.

I understand that this is because it's a date time object but again there are no separate objects for date and time in .net so how can I parse them separately as they are?

Comment: What types are these in the database (and which database platform)?

Comment: `date` and `time` in `SQL Server 2012`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should store a single `datetime` (or `datetime2`) in the database, rather than separate `date` and `time` fields.  But to address the casting issue - consider that `time` in SQL Server is mapped to `TimeSpan` in .NET.

```csharp
var date = (DateTime)sdr.GetValue(5);
var time = (TimeSpan)sdr.GetValue(6);
var dateTime = date.Add(time);
```

Comment: Thankyou. I stored them seperate so i could perform searches on `date` and `time` seperately. You solved my problem of casting issue but the issue of my .net date object getting empty time stamp while casting is still there.

Comment: There's no working around that.  .NET only has a `DateTime` type.  There is no type for a date without a time.  There is `LocalDate` in the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, but you would have to go through `DateTime` first since you're coming from SQL.